# How to kill the Warden

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you defeat the [Warden](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Warden) in Minecraft?

Comment: The point of the Warden is to be avoided by either not summoning it or not getting attacked by it. Killing it and also not getting killed by it when it is angry at you is supposed to be very hard and various "cheesing" methods have been made impossible during the snapshot phase, probably more will. Of course that doesn't mean that there aren't any, those are then the valid answers here. But they might get outdated at any time, so test something in Creative first if you want to be sure.

Comment: @FabianRöling That comment seems like a decent answer. Why not post it as an answer to the question?

Comment: @User23415 No, not at all. "Just don't do it." is not a valid answer to a "How do I do this?" question. I just wanted to give some background on why this is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cheeze him, then get a bow or two and infinity/lots of arrows. Make a hole then get the Warden stuck in it, then go 19 blocks away from him. When you're there just shoot him with arrows untill he dies.